# template matches twice when it should match once

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <shortbody>
        <text>
            testing
        </text>
        <text>
            shortbody
        </text>
    </shortbody>
    <body>
        <paragraph>
            <text>
                A new version of xsltransform.net is released!
            </text>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
            <text>
                We have added the following new features:
            </text>
        </paragraph>
    </body>
</document>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="body">
    <result>
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//shortbody" />
      </p>

      <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
        <xsl:element name="paragraph">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body/paragraph/text | shortbody/text">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result is ([see fiddle here](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQw)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
testing

shortbody
<result>
  <p>
    testing

    shortbody
  </p>
  <paragraph>
    A new version of xsltransform.net is released!
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph>
    We have added the following new features:
  </paragraph>
</result>
```

I cannot understand why templates for `shortbody/text` are called twice so it ends outside my XML, but are not called twice for `body/paragrap/text`? I have tried a lot of different ways to match, but every time `shortbody` ends up outside my XML elements. Why is this and how can I change my XSLT so the template only matches the call from within `<xsl:template match="body">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another template that matches the root element, `document`.

Try adding this:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The text outside your XML's root element is because default templates apply to the root element, which recursively get the child nodes processed, ending up copying the text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the result of the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule). Since you have no template matching `/` or `document`, the template applied to `document` is this built-in template:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This applies templates to the children of `document`, including `shortbody` - and in the absence of a template matching `shortbody`, the same the default template:

```
<xsl:template match="shortbody">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

applies templates to the children of `shortbody`.

One way to prevent this is to organize your stylesheet this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/document">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="shortbody">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the absence of templates matching `body` and `text`. Here, the built-in template rules do exactly what is necessary.